# Dropping iPhone 3GS Support for new app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Is it possible to drop the support of iPhone 3GS for new App?
Because I'm doing porting from iPad game to iPhone. The 480*320 resolution is too small. Its very hard to port my current game on it.. but iPhone4/4s with high resolution works fine!

Thanks

Comment: Why is 480x320 resolution too small? You'll have 480 and 320 points anyway. It's only image quality that differs.

Comment: because the game have many text on screen interface, while under 480x320 resolution, they looks very blur and most are unreadable. It needs a very large modification on it to looks 'normally' on 3GS.
The game and resources are originally designed for 1024x768

Comment: can't wait to play it on an iPhone4!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1) you can specify inside Info.plist.

There is no direct way to limit "device-support" to the iPhone 4(S) / iPad (2), but you can ask for `front-facing-camera`because that's only included in the iPhone-4-familiy :) On the other hand you'll also drop support for the original iPad if you use this way …

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure that you can do it from a build level. But you can do it from code level by detecting the device version like this (Not the best way of doing it),

```
- (NSString *) platformString{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
    return platform;
}
```

Hope this will help you to a certain extent.

Comment: thank you, but is it possible to block 3GS users to download my app in iTunes side?

Comment: As far as know, don't think it is possible. But you can insert  UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities entry to the PList and try what Angelo has mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible as I took a look in this great reference chart
http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix

The best closest is to required front-camera or gyroscope but it will cut out iPad 1 from your support devices. I think I have to admit and do my best to support iPhone 3GS, I just don't want users to download and experience something bad even if it's small portion of users are still using it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Required device capabilities` to your info.plist and the value `camera-flash`. This will limit the app to only run on devices with camera flash (e.g. iPhone 4/4S) or use `front-facing-camera` to include iPad 2 and latest gen iPod Touch.